# Android music-streaming app

Tags: java, performance, beginner, android, audio

This is my first time building an Android app or even using Java in the first place. All of this code does work, but I'm hoping to optimize it or find out if things could be done more easily than how I've done them.

**radio.java**

```
package com.example.jacob.wutk;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class radio extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean isMediaPlayerStarted = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
        setMediaPlayer();
    }

    public void setMediaPlayer() {
        try {
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            String url = "http://streamer.cci.utk.edu:8000/wutk-vorbis"; // your URL here

            final ImageButton imb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playPause);

            imb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!isMediaPlayerStarted) {
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        isMediaPlayerStarted = true;
                    } else {
                        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            imb.setImageResource(R.drawable.play1);
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                        } else {
                            imb.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause1);
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }}
```

**activity_radio.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:context="com.example.jacob.wutk.radio">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/background_mic1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="1.0dip"
        android:paddingLeft="4.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="4.0dip"
        android:paddingTop="5.0dip">
       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/playPause"
           android:layout_width="0.0dip"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_weight="1.0"
           android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
           android:clickable="true"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:onClick="playPauseMusic"
           android:src="@drawable/play1"/>
       <ImageView
           android:layout_width="0.0dip"
           android:layout_height="fill_parent"
           android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
           android:layout_weight="1.0"
           android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
           android:scaleType="fitCenter"
           android:src="@drawable/logo"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[**Debug version of app**](http://bit.ly/2a26Un4)

Answer (score 2):

There's really not a lot going on in what you've posted, so there's not much to pick apart.  Really the only functional change I'd mention is that there's a `MediaController` class available that you can use that provides play, pause, and seek functionality (including a standard UI that Android users are familiar with) that you might want to check out.  That said, it's 100% find to use your own UI if that's a design decision and not just the result of being unaware.  Also, you don't update the play/pause UI the first time the `MediaPlayer is started.  Other than that, it's mostly code style and convention issues that I see.

1. Classes are usually named using PascalCase (you have lowercase).  Also, convention is to use the word "Activity" when extending an Activity, so your `radio` class should probably be `RadioActivity`.
2. The prefix `set` is generally reserved for setter methods - methods that update a variable value and often do some pre- or post-processing work around that update.  I would probably call `setMediaPlayer` something like `initializeMediaPlayer` or `startMediaPlayer`.
3. You could break `setMediaPlayer` into multiple smaller methods.
4. You probably don't want that whole method body in the `try` block - figure out what's going to potentially `throw` and move the rest out.  This is a bit of a nitpick and isn't critical for a fairly small function like this, but it's a good habit to get into.
5. `imb` is a bad variable name - it's not clear what kind of object is being referenced.
6. Your code might be a little easier to read with less nesting.  I'd probably move the functionality in the `onClick` to its own method, and call that method in the `onClick`.
7. Why is the `imb` variable `final` and not a member variable?  It's OK to do this, but there doesn't seem to be clear reason - you're using member variables elsewhere.
8. Again, not a critical issue, but Android convention is to prefix `private` variables with `m`, so `mediaPlayer` would become `mMediaPlayer`.
9. Why is `setMediaPlayer` public?  Always be as restrictive as possible.
10. `isMediaPlayerStarted` will default to `false` so you don't need to set it.
11. If an error is thrown, do you really want to print the stack trace?  This might be fine if that's what you want, but I suspect that's either the IDE's decision or the result of a copy/paste...  What error might be thrown here?  What could be a possible source?  What do you really want to do if that happens?
12. If you're not using any `ImageButton` methods, you don't need to cast it - `findViewById` returns a `View`, which has a `setOnClickListener` method, so the cast doesn't do anything.